# xgboost - difference between XGBClassifier.feature_importances_ and XGBClassifier.get_booster().get_fscore()

Tags: boosting

What is the difference between get_fscore() and feature_importances? Both are explained as
**feature importance** but the importance values are different.

```
# model_smote = XGBClassifier()
# model_smote.fit(X_train_smote, y_train_smote)
model_smote = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = XGBClassifier(),
    param_grid=parameters,
    scoring='roc_auc',
    cv=5,
    verbose=2,
    return_train_score=True
)
model_smote.fit(X_train_smote, y_train_smote)
xgb = model_smote.best_estimator_
```

```
feature_importances = pd.Series(xgb.get_booster().get_fscore()).sort_values(ascending=False)
feature_importances.plot(kind='bar', title='Feature Importances', figsize=(10, 10))
```

### get_fscore()

[class xgboost.Booster(params=None, cache=(), model_file=None) - get_fscore(fmap='')](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.get_fscore)

> Get feature importance of each feature.

[image]

### feature_importances_

[class xgboost.XGBClassifier - property feature_importances_: numpy.ndarray](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.feature_importances_)

```
feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(
    data=xgb.feature_importances_,
    index=xgb.get_booster().feature_names,
    columns=['Importance']
).sort_values('Importance', ascending=False)
feature_importances.plot(kind='bar', title='Feature Importances', figsize=(10, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `get_fscore()`, but regarding `get_score()`:

First, make sure that both use the same kind of feature importance.
They do not use the same kind by default.

- The kind for `XGBClassifier.feature_importance_` is shown in
  `XGBClassifier.importance_type`. You can set this when you instantiate the instance of `XGBClassifier`.
- The kind for `XGBClassifier.get_booster.get_score()` is set by the `importance_type` argument to the method.

Then, the values differ in two ways.

1. `feature_importances_` has the same values as `get_score()`, except that the values of the former are scaled so that they sum to 1.
2. `feature_importances_` includes features with value 0, but `get_score()` does not.

Answer (score 0):

From [xgboost documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.get_fscore):

`get_fscore` method returns (by deafult) the `weight` importance of each feature that has importance greater than 0. That is, features never used to split the data are disconsidered.

`feature_importances_` attribute is the average (over all targets) feature importance based on the `importance_type` parameter that is passed when initializing the model.

My guess is that the default value of `importance_type` is different than `"weight"`, making the two representing different things.

You can try initialize the model with `importance_type="weigth"` and see if the two converges to same values, still considering that `feature_importances_` includes zero importance features.